# TikZ: How to get a few smooth grid lines for surface plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to produce smooth surface plots with smooth grid lines using TikZ/pgfplots. Usually, this can be achieved using e.g. `[samples=100]`, but this also draws 100 grid lines. I basically want that

1. the surface and the grid lines are computed using many help points (samples) to make it smooth
2. but only a fraction of the grid lines shall be drawn.

I've browsed the documentation, but couldn't find anything helpful in that direction. All the surface plot examples which I found showed edgy grid lines giving the surface a faceted look instead of the smooth pictures I want to achieve.

Here's a minimal working example for two different sample values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[samples=10]
      \addplot3[surf, domain=-2:2] {x^2-y^2};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[samples=100]
      \addplot3[surf, domain=-2:2] {x^2-y^2};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output from MWE]

In the first picture, the lines are too edgy, in the second picture all the many lines are drawn. How can I achieve a smooth looking surface with **only a few**, but **smooth**, grid lines?

Comment: You can get the `surf` and `mesh` independently with `\addplot3[surf, shader=interp,domain=-2:2] {x^2-y^2};
\addplot3[mesh,samples=20,draw=black,domain=-2:2] {x^2-y^2};`. and increase the mesh sample size until you are happy with it. Use it without the `[samples=100]` option in the axis environment.

Comment: @percusse throw in a screenshot, and your comment is an answer :)

Comment: @cmhughes Since I am still a novice on `pgfplots`  I don't know if that is the way to go. If Kristin thinks it is useful, I would make it an answer but thanks for the pat on the shoulder, though :)

Comment: @percusse Thanks, separating surface and grid lines using mesh is a good beginning. However, for the mesh, I want to draw, say, only 5 or 10 lines per dimension, but they shall look smooth nevertheless. I could say: forget about the surface coloring, just give me a few nicely curved grid lines to describe the surface. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: That's why I didn't make it an answer and I don't know a quick fix yet. Maybe @ChristianFeuersänger or someone else drop by and share their view.

Comment: It sounds like you want your own custom mesh. How about adding a sequence of parametric curves, say `(x(t),y(t),z(t))=(x,t,x^2-t^2)` where `x` has `100` sample points on `[-2,2]`, and `t` takes integer values between `[-2,2]`. You could then repeat this using `(x(t),y(t),z(t))=(t,y,t^2-y^2)`.

Comment: OK, when using such a custom mesh (I generated the points with an external program) I can get really nice curves. But how could I then hide (or fade) the curves of the background? (`mesh` also doesn't hide background lines, only `surf` can do it, if I understand the manual correctly). Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer of pgfplots for "mesh plots with smooth boundary" is its `patchplots` library, combined with one of the higher-order patch types. Take, for example, `patch type=biquadratic` : its boundaries are second order polynomials. This allows to provide a coarse-grained grid combined with smoothness.

The cost for such a format is to provide patches in a nontrival sequence: coordinates

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

are interpreted as the following points on a (single) rectangle:

```
3  6  2
7  8  5
0  4  1
```

the next 9 points make up the next rectangle and so forth. Here, points 0,1,2,3 make up the corners whereas points 4,5,6,7 are used to define the boundary parables. Point 8 is only relevant if you have `shader=interp`; I think it is unused for `mesh` plots. 
If you combine the approach with `shader=faceted interp`, you get smooth fill colors + mesh lines.

Examples and images can be found in [Section 5.6 Patchplots Library](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf).

Of course, the cost is to manually arrange your input coordinate sequence in the format shown above - one set of 9 arranged points for every patch. To simplify this, you can also provide a single list of coordinates, and a connectivity table which tells `pgfplots` that patch 0 consists of vertices with indices #42 #5# #7 #3 #30 #12 ... (see the `patch table` option of `pgfplots`).

The alternatives are (as percusse already mentioned) to combine two plots: one which only fills the surface and one which provides the mesh. However, this has a severe limitation: `pgfplots` only considers image depths inside of one single plot (compare the discussion and the alternative solution described in [Section "5.6.4 Drawing Grids" in the patch plots library](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf).

`pgfplots` has no option to "draw only each Nth mesh line".

**EDIT**

I have just realized that your example function *is* a biquadratic function! As such, you only need one patch to capture its boundary without any loss in precision - and the effort to put input coordinates into the requested sequence is limited to only 9 points. That can be done by means of `\addplot table[z expr=<expression>]`.

Only the color interpolation is of first order (because pdf only supports bilinear interpolation). Consequently, you can get the effect for your example function using `shader=faceted interp` combined with `patch refines` - and just one patch as input:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[patch,patch refines=3,shader=faceted interp,patch type=biquadratic] 
        table[z expr=x^2-y^2]
    {
        x y
        -2 -2
        2 -2
        2 2
        -2 2
        0 -2
        2 0
        0 2
        -2 0
        0 0
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is it with `patch refines=2`:

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! I didn't come across the patch library so far. It looks quite complicated, but the results are promising!

Comment: I fear that it has, indeed, a quite complicated input format. Its intended audience is people importing high order geometries from numerical programs or from CAD programs. But it should be applicable anyway.

Comment: Note that I have just realized that your example function actually *is* a biquadratic function -- and can be represented by just one patch. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful addition! And makes things a little less complicated.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable the grids with the "shader=inter" as suggested by @percusse . Then set the grids to whatever you want. Here is an example where the grids are each 1 (unit) distance for x and y.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[samples=60]
      \addplot3[surf, domain=-2:2, shader=interp] {x^2-y^2};
      \foreach \xx in {-2.0,-1.0,...,2.0}
      {
        \addplot3+[domain=-2:2, line width=0.1mm, mark=none, color=black, samples y=0]
         ({\xx}, {x}, {\xx*\xx-x^2});
      }

      % y=constant grids lines
      \foreach \yy in {-2.0,-1.0,...,2.0}
      {
         \addplot3[domain=-2:2, line width=0.1mm, mark=none, color=black, samples y=0]
         ({x}, {\yy}, {x^2-\yy*\yy});
      }


   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and here the figure:

[image: Grids separated one unit on each direction]