# 3d interactive image using gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, 3d, gnuplot

I want to be able to see 3D data (a clouds of points) as in any *gnuplot* terminal - at least to be able to rotate as it is for images on p. 171 in [this document](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~wjarosz/publications/dissertation/appendixB.pdf).

Is it possible to insert a script in `.plt` *gnuplot* format or to generate data in some another format suitable for adding in LaTeX document (I use LyX)?

What is general approach to add such a 3D interactive images to PDF?

Comment: Have a look at TikZ and PGFplots.

Comment: @user124577 Thank you for the hint. What tags are related to searching that?

Comment: That depends. Just try to find something like "pgf 3d data" (like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118131/how-to-plot-a-surface-from-a-set-of-data/118274#118274)

Comment: The first question is how does PDF do it?  Second, does hyperref or tikz support those features?  I should also note that at 8.7Mb for an 11 page document, it would seem that the animation consists of selecting one of many images stored.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Bad news :(. But it may worth this.

Comment: @John : This is embedded PRC or U3D data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asymptote (http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) is what you are after. It produces interactive 3D models in the PRC format which are eventually embedded using the `media9` LaTeX package. See [Sect. 7 of the `media9` documentation](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#section.7) which explains the procedure and which contains an Asymptote generated example.

Comment: I hope it is not too complex to deal with.

Comment: Well, the learning curve of Asymptote is rather steep, but the web page is full of examples and you may get help here too.